# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()

Tags: php

When i try to login on my website i got this error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in C:\wamp\www\Website\index2.php on line 10

And there is the code

```
<?php require 'Connections/Connections.php'; ?>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Entrar'])){


        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];

        $result = $con->query("SELECT * from user where Email='$Email' AND Password='$Password'");

        $row = $result->fetch(MYSQLI_BOTH);

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["User ID"] = $row['UserID'];

        hearder('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you show what's displayed by putting `var_dump($result);` straight after you use `$con->query(...)`?

Comment: mysqli_result has no method named `fetch`. You want something from [that](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) list (fetch_assoc most likely). Your code is also vulnerable to sql injections. Also not hashing passwords (For example using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is considered bad practice. And again... `hearder` is certainly wrong.